# Fifty Shades of "idiot"

Tags: vocabulary, style

I'm from North Germany where the dialect "Platt" is second language - in Platt you can even call someone an ass without much risk of a defamation suit. Likewise, "Döspaddel" (literally: idiot) is almost loving tender. Going through synonyms on Google Translate (and excluding "fool", which has additional connotations), "nitwit" seemed the "weakest" shade of idiot to me, but still... Is there an English equivalent of calling someone stupid without being harsh? (Note that "among friends" doesn't count.)

Comment: **Silly ass** is close to it. (UK ass rather than US) Much of the time, the context is as important than the word chosen.

Comment: An interesting question!  But I agree with Ronald, we need to know more about context.  Among friends, you might call someone "dummy", but in a work context, I can't imagine calling someone stupid unless I phrased it in a *very* roundabout way.

Comment: NOT among friends, I'm pretty confident that no, there's no way to call someone stupid in English without causing offence.

Comment: @RonaldSole - posh people a few generations ago pronounced the 'ass' in 'silly ass' like the modern 'arse' which meant that our kindly old music teacher at Alleyn's caused much merriment among the boys.

Comment: Lots of expressions (especially, older idiomatic usages) are inherently "light-hearted, whimsical" - so they imply ***relaxed friendly banter*** rather than being deliberately offensive. ***You daft 'aporth**!* and ***Don't be such a silly noodle**!*, for example.

Comment: @gotube - if someone I considered a friend called me stupid, and meant it as an assessment of my intellectual faculties, they would cease to be a friend from that time. Few things are as wounding or annoying.

Comment: Beware: an _ass_ in AmE is very very different from an _ass_ in BrE.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Of course, but you also know that friends often insult each other in various ways, including jokingly calling them stupid in a variety of terms. "Dumb ass" is probably the most common form of joking insult among friends where I live, but only among friends.

Answer (score -1):

**Clueless** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clueless)) Lacking knowledge or understanding; uninformed; oblivious. Without any clues or hints.

It is the closest you can get to "idiot" in formal English without causing offense. No it does not exactly mean "idiot".

Comment: nor is it likely not to cause offense.

Comment: But you could get away with it :)

Answer (score -2):

It's **very** informal, but you can call someone **blonde** or accuse them of being **blonde**, which is the same as clueless (no offense meant to any blonde-headed readers).

You can also lovingly call someone a **dummy** or a **big dummy** and not have the person take offense.

Comment: Worth noting (maybe?) that terms of abuse, even light-hearted, that use e.g. old medical terms for intellectual impairment and disability such as 'idiot', 'cretin', 'imbecile', and, yes, 'idiot', have the capacity to greatly offend. People with Down's syndrome ('Down syndrome' in the US) used to be called 'mongoloid idiots' until comparatively recently. A word widely used for a clumsy person, I gather, namely 'spaz' or 'spastic', is considered deeply offensive in the UK. People in the UK often consider it to be one of the most offensive terms related to disability.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Cf. recent music news - https://www.okayplayer.com/culture/why-is-spaz-offensive-beyonce-lizzo.html

Comment: @HaukeReddmann - her argument seems to be that black (or Black) people use 'spaz' as an AAVE word, and for 'white' people to be shocked is marginalising black people. I think she not only 'hadn't heard' that it was offensive in the UK, but 'hasn't heard' that not all British people are white.